# Can't write data using Html5 File API

Tags: javascript, html, filewriter, fileapi

I followed the [tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) to learn something about the File API in html5
but,while I met these code

```
fs.root.getFile('log',{create:true},function(fileEntry){
  fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter){

    fileWriter.onwriteend=function(e){
        alert("end")

    }
    fileWriter.onerror=function(e){
       alert("error")
    }

    var bb=new window.WebKitBlobBuilder()
    bb.append('hello')

    fileWriter.write(bb.getBlob('text/plain'))
  },errorHandler)

},errorHandler)
```

I always met "error"
and while I set `alert(e.toString())`in error event,it appears to be `[object ProgressEvent]`,
My browser is chromium 13,
Do someone has some ideas  ? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra '})' after alert('end'). Please post the complete testcase one can check out (e.g. on http://jsfiddle.net/), it makes it much easier to help you.

Did you try to log (BTW alert() is old, use `console.log()`) the list of properties of the error event? Does it maybe have a `e.code`? Although I don't think it's expected to be a ProgressEvent.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that it supports the chrome13+ only. please check it

Answer (score 0):

your filewriter could be failing for any number of reasons. the following code might help you determine which one:

```
fileWriter.onerror = function (event) {
  switch (event.target.error.code) {
  case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
    console.error('NOT_FOUND_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
    console.error('SECURITY_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.ABORT_ERR:
    console.error('ABORT_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
    console.error('NOT_READABLE_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.ENCODING_ERR:
    console.error('ENCODING_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR:
    console.error('NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
    console.error('INVALID_STATE_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.SYNTAX_ERR:
    console.error('SYNTAX_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
    console.error('INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
    console.error('QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR:
    console.error('TYPE_MISMATCH_ERR');
    break;
  case FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR:
    console.error('PATH_EXISTS_ERR');
    break;
  default:
    console.error('Unknown Error: ' + event.target.error.code);
    break;
  }
};
```